# EJS file not rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, ejs

I am having the problem witj .ejs files. The synthax just doesn`t seem to work for some reason:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     
    SomeText
    <br>
        <%- body  %>
    <br>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am running a small Node.js application and I set up EJS as a view engine:
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

When I hover over the <%- and %>, it says: 'Special characters must be escaped : [ > ].(spec-char-escape)'

I have installed extension called EJS Language support and the have installed ejs package:
"dependencies": {
"ejs": "^3.1.8"
},

How to get around this error?

Comment: Please post your code as code, not as an image. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557. This link might be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This seems like it's a question about configuring your code editor, not necessarily about programming.  Hard to be sure...

Comment: You say it's "not rendering" in the title, and something about an error on hover in your editor.  Can you add some detail about what happens when you try to request the page with a browser?  Debugging details are key...

Comment: The problem is that when I type any EJS tag in the body of the document, Visual Studio Code does not recognise it as a EJS synthax I suppose. I also did put this code into settings.json file: {
    "files.associations": {
        "*.ejs": "html"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "ejs": "html"
    },
    "htmlhint.options": {
        "spec-char-escape": false,
        "doctype-first": false
    },
    "html.validate.scripts": false,
}     and now the VS Code still does not recognise any of EJS synthax

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I opened the setting.json file and inserted this into:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.ejs": "html"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "ejs": "html"
    },
    "htmlhint.options": {
        "spec-char-escape": false,
        "doctype-first": false
    },
    "html.validate.scripts": false,
}
```

Now the Visual Studio recognizes the EJS file and the code can run.